# Apache Camel MQ connection pool and timer routes

Tags: timer, apache-camel, connection-pooling

I have a web service which works with Camel to receive Soap calls and writes messages into the queue. The same service also has a timer route which checks the queue and processes the messages one by one. The web service is running on Tomcat containers on multiple servers and the Back-end queue is Websphere MQ.

I have a config in Tomcat context.xml like this:

```
<Resource name="jms/MyQueueConnectionFactory" auth="Container"
    type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
    factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
    description="My Queue Connection Factory "
    CHANNEL="CLIENT.MYCHANNEL" HOST="localhost.com" PORT="3663"
    QMGR="MYCHANNEL" TRAN="1" UCP="Y" />    
<Environment name="jms/QmgrUsername" value="appuser" type="java.lang.String" />
<Environment name="jms/QmgrPassword" value="password1" type="java.lang.String" />
```

I'm using a DSL router in the spring config as:

```
<bean id="EventRouter" class="com.myapp.router.EventRouter" />

<bean id="camelTracer" class="org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer">
    <property name="traceExceptions" value="true"/>
    <property name="traceInterceptors" value="true"/>
    <property name="logLevel" value="INFO"/>
    <property name="logName" value="com.myapp.camel"/>
</bean>

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <consumerTemplate id="consumer" />
    <template id="producer" /> 
    <routeBuilder ref="EventRouter" />
</camelContext>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="MyQueueConnectionFactory"
    jndi-name="java:comp/env/jms/MyQueueConnectionFactory" cache="true"
    lookup-on-startup="false" proxy-interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="MQUserName"
    jndi-name="java:comp/env/jms/QmgrUsername" cache="true"
    lookup-on-startup="true" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="MQPassword"
    jndi-name="java:comp/env/jms/QmgrPassword" cache="true"
    lookup-on-startup="true" />

<bean id="myQueue" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref bean="CredentialsConnectionFactory"></ref>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="CredentialsConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="MyQueueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" ref="MQUserName" />
    <property name="password" ref="MQPassword" />
</bean>
```

In my EventRouter, I have defined routes as:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.ExchangePattern;
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.myapp.camelconsumer.QueueConsumer;
import com.myapp.camelproducer.QueueProducer;

public class EventRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    final private static String camelRouteURI = "cxf:/EventService?wsdlURL=classpath:wsdl/EventService.wsdl&serviceClass=EventService";
    final private static String inQueue = "myQueue:queue:QAW.MYAPP.IN";
    final private static String timerUrl = "timer://EventService?period=5m";

    @Autowired
    private QueueProducer producer;

    @Autowired
    private QueueConsumer consumer;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from(timerUrl)
            .bean(consumer, "processQueueOnTimer('queueTimer')");

        from(camelRouteURI).recipientList(simple("direct:${header.operationName}"));

        from("direct:useEventService")
            .bean(producer, "processQueueRoute('useEventService')")
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
            .to(inQueue)
            .bean(producer, "setSuccessResponse('success')");       
    }

}
```

The producer is pretty straight-forward, it gets a Soap call, validates the message and does something, then puts it to the MQ. The timer consumer polls the queue every 5 minutes and processes the queue messages.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.PollingConsumer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.cambia.enroll.web.service.CheckHealthRequest;
import com.myapp.exception.InternalErrorException;
import com.myapp.elog.exception.QueueException;

@Component
public class QueueConsumer {

    private static String inQueue = "myQueue:queue:QAW.MYAPP.IN";   

    public void processQueueOnTimer(String queueTimer, Exchange exchange) {
        try {           
            synchronized (this) {
                readFromQueue(exchange, inQueue);           
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An unknown exception occured in processQueueOnTimer, throw Internal error", e);
        }           
    }

    private void readFromQueue(Exchange exchange, String queueName) throws QueueException, Exception {
        String operationName = "";      
        CamelContext springCamelContext = exchange.getContext();
        Endpoint endpoint = springCamelContext.getEndpoint(queueName);
        PollingConsumer consumer = endpoint.createPollingConsumer();
        Exchange queueMessage = exchange;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            int timeout = 10000; // Default value if cannot read from property file
            // Read all messages from the queue
            while(true) {               
                queueMessage = consumer.receive(timeout);                   
                if (null == queueMessage || null == queueMessage.getIn()) {
                    break;
                }
                //process each queue message

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new QueueException("Failure in readFromQueue for " + operationName + ": ", queueMessage, e);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Sorry for the long message, my questions are below  :)

1) How will Tomcat and spring manage my connections here for the producer component? Is it pooled or not? I use the UCP="Y" flag in the queue connection factory but is that applicable to the Tomcat pool or is it only on the MQ Manager side? I use **.to(inQueue)** to put messages into queue.
2) Am I using a pooled connection for the consumer on the timer route? I'm getting the default Exchange body generated by camel, and then I get the CamelContext, Endpoint, PollingConsumer using that. Am I doing this correctly for a timer route, or are there other ways to get a pooled connection.
3) How do I monitor JMS connections status? Is there a way I can view the number of connections in the pool, new connections and connections that have been released etc?
4) Are there any issues using a consumer client or a timer route on multiple instances trying to access the same back-end queue? So far I have not noticed any unusual activity on the logs.

Thanks.